# How to create map with mapped value?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have a set of strings and a hash function (or any unilateral function) and a test function. I would like to create a map from the input string to its hash value, which passes the test function, with Java 8 stream. My question is how to write the `keyMapper` in `Collectors.toMap()`?

Pseudo code:

```
Map<String, String> result = inputStrings.stream()
    .map(str -> hashFunc(str))
    .filter(hash -> hash.startsWith("00"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(hash -> ???,  // the original input string is lost
                              Function::identity));
```

In other functional programming language, I could zip the input stream with the filtered hash stream, but Java 8 does not have `zip`. Also, in `map()`, I could return the pair of the input string and the hash value, so that the input will be passed down to the collector. But Java 8 does not have pair or tuple either.

It seems the old for loop is the most concise solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that no lambda will work there.  There are a few alternative options, but the one I'd use would be:

```
Map<String, String> result = inputStrings.stream()
    .map(str -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(str, hashFunc(str)))
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().startsWith("00"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

(If I weren't collecting to a `Map`, I would create my own custom tuple type appropriate for the use case rather than using `Map.Entry`, but here `Map.Entry` is a sufficient type.)

Comment: It will throw duplicate key exception if inputStrings contains a duplicate element.

Comment: @Sandeep yup.  That looks to be working as intended based on the OP's post.

Comment: Well, assume the inputStrings is a `Set<String>`.

Comment: @CrendKing in that case it's not an issue, and this code should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Well, even Java allows a purely functional solution, however, it’s readability heavily suffers from the fact that there are no true function types:

```
Map<String, String> result = inputStrings.stream()
    .map(str -> { String hash=hashFunc(str);
                  return (Function<BinaryOperator<String>,String>)f->f.apply(str, hash); })
    .filter(f -> f.apply((s,hash)->hash).startsWith("00"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(f->f.apply((s,hash)->s), f->f.apply((s,hash)->hash)));
```

If the number of rejected entries is expected to be rather low compared the the number of accepted entries, you could simply create a complete map eagerly and remove the wrong ones afterwards:

```
Map<String, String> result = inputStrings.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                 Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), str -> hashFunc(str)),
                 map -> { map.values().removeIf(s->!s.startsWith("00")); return map; }));
```

This might be even more efficient than wrapping the elements and hash results in whatever pair type before eventually adding them to the `Map` (creating another map-specific kind of pair, aka `Map.Entry`). But it likely will have a higher peek memory usage, of course.

Comment: Both your `removeIf` version and Louis code are O(n), but yours requires more space if there are values to be removed, correct?

Comment: As already said in my answer, the peek memory usage will likely be higher. But memory management is not that simple to make that an absolute statement. It’s only a tendency that the programmer should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If the hashing function is cheap you could filter before mapping.

```
Map<String, String> result = inputStrings.stream()
    .filter(val -> hashFunc(val).startsWith("00"))
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identy(), this::hashFunc));
```

The `distinct` operation is to ensure each value only occurs once as a key - they will map to the same hash value.

Comment: 1) Collision could happen, so the `distinct()` is not technically correct. 2) Hashing could be expensive.

Comment: @CrendKing 1) OP wants to create a map from value to hash which means you will have only 1 entry for each hash hence the distinct 2) I prefaced with the comment 'if the hashing function is cheap'